# I want to change the background color of only one item of Navigation Menu(By Google) in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group1"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/11"
        android:title="@string/ " />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/111"
        android:title="@string/ " />


</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group2"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/22"
        android:title="@string/ " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/222"
        android:title="@string/ " />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/2222"
        android:title="@string/ " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/22222"
        android:title="@string/ " />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/21"
        android:title="@string/ "
        android:visible="false" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/25"
        android:title="@string/" />
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group3"
    android:checkableBehavior="none">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/31"
        android:title=" " />


</group>
```

I want to change the background color of the item(id: 21) of group 2 only. Any Idea? Currently it is not visible, however it will show on the click of the previous item and its background color needs to be changed.